# DotNet Restore task doesn't restore project when run from an Azure DevOps Template, hosted from a separate repo

Tags: .net, azure-devops

I'm running an ADO template from a repo that I'm adding to the pipeline. Within this template, I'm running a DotNet Restore command (via DotNetCoreCLI@2 task).
When I add a DotNet restore task, as shown below, to the pipeline it works as expected, and the projects are restored, and shows which packages are being restored etc.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use .Net Core 6.x
  inputs:
    version: 6.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
  displayName: ".Net Restore"
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: |
      **/<ProjectA>/<ProjectA>.csproj
      **/<ProjectB>/<ProjectB>.csproj
      **/<ProjectC>/<ProjectC>.csproj
      **/<ProjectD>/<ProjectD>.csproj
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '<FeedName>'
```

**Task output**:

```
1>Target "Restore" in file "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.407\NuGet.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\<ProjectA>\<ProjectA>.csproj" (entry point):
       Task "RemoveDuplicates"
       Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
       Using "RestoreTask" task from assembly "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.407\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll".
       Task "RestoreTask"
         (in) RestoreGraphItems Count '13'
         (in) RestoreDisableParallel 'False'
         (in) RestoreNoCache 'False'
         (in) RestoreIgnoreFailedSources 'False'
         (in) RestoreRecursive 'True'
         (in) RestoreForce 'False'
         (in) HideWarningsAndErrors 'False'
         (in) RestoreForceEvaluate 'False'
         (in) RestorePackagesConfig 'False'
         X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET.
         Running restore with 2 concurrent jobs.
         Reading project file D:\a\1\s\<ProjectB>\<ProjectB>.csproj.
         Reading project file D:\a\1\s\<ProjectA>\<ProjectA>.csproj.
         Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\<ProjectB>\<ProjectB>.csproj...
         Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\<ProjectA>\<ProjectA>.csproj...
         Restoring packages for .NETStandard,Version=v2.1...
         Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
         <starts going through list of packages>
```

When I run the tasks from an Azure DevOps Template, that's hosted in a separate repo, it fails saying there's "nothing to do". Below is the example that I've tested in the template:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use .Net Core 6.x
  inputs:
    version: 6.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".Net Restore"
  enabled: ${{ parameters.EnableRestore }} 
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: |
      **/<ProjectA>/<ProjectA>.csproj
      **/<ProjectB>/<ProjectB>.csproj
      **/<ProjectC>/<ProjectC>.csproj
      **/<ProjectD>/<ProjectD>.csproj
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '8ce85194-d455-4f34-a534-c425d96988b8'
```

**Task output:**

```
1>Target "Restore" in file "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\NuGet.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\<ProjectRepo>\<ProjectA>\<ProjectA>.csproj" (entry point):
       Task "RemoveDuplicates"
       Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
       Using "RestoreTask" task from assembly "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll".
       Task "RestoreTask"
         (in) RestoreGraphItems Count '11'
         (in) RestoreDisableParallel 'False'
         (in) RestoreNoCache 'False'
         (in) RestoreIgnoreFailedSources 'False'
         (in) RestoreRecursive 'True'
         (in) RestoreForce 'False'
         (in) HideWarningsAndErrors 'False'
         (in) RestoreForceEvaluate 'False'
         (in) RestorePackagesConfig 'False'
         X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET.
         Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
       Done executing task "RestoreTask".
     1>Done building target "Restore" in project "<ProjectA>.csproj".
     1>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\<ProjectRepo>\<ProjectA>\<ProjectA>.csproj" (Restore target(s)).
```

When running the tasks in both instances, it shows that the dotnet command as the same, with slight variation on the tempNuGet name:
`C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore D:\a\1\s\<ProjectRepo>\<ProjectA>\<ProjectA>.csproj --configfile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_50578.config --verbosity Detailed`

The only other odd thing I noticed about the pipeline output, is that it changes the URL of the artefactory from a hardcoded name to ***:

`https://<OrgName>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<ArtefactoryName>/nuget/v3/index.json #(works)`
`https://***.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<ArtefactoryName>/nuget/v3/index.json #(fails)`

to add the repo & Template to the pipeline, I've done the following:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: DevOps
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: "<RepoEndpoint>"
    name: "<RepoLocation>"
    ref: "TestBranch"
```

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: DevOps

- template: <TemplateName>@DevOps
```

Unfortunately with this output the task completes as if there's no issues, so I'm struggling to find any output that would help troubleshoot this further, like how it would if it were to fail. I've also tried defining the environment variable `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` however this doesn't change the output.

I would like to know either what I've done wrong here, or what I need to do to get the projects to restore as expected.

If you have any other questions, let me know and I'll try and answer them.